# How to print page function after columnize function is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, printing

Hi i have some problem to ask you. Now i need to print page after function columnize is finished but print function is work before columnize function is finishing. How to print page after columnize function finished in script .

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var content_height = 711;   // the height of the content, discluding the header/footer
        var page = 1;               // the beginning page number to show in the footer
        function buildNewsletter() {
            if ($('#newsletterContent').contents().length > 0) {
                // when we need to add a new page, use a jq object for a template
                // or use a long HTML string, whatever your preference
                $page = $("#page_template").clone().addClass("page").css("display", "block");

                // fun stuff, like adding page numbers to the footer
                $page.find(".footer #lbl_pageNum").append(page);
                $page.find(".footer #lbl_pageNum2").append(page);
                //create label to recive data

                $("body").append($page);
                page++;

                // here is the columnizer magic
                $('#newsletterContent').columnize({
                    columns: 1,
                    target: ".page:last .content",
                    overflow: {
                        height: content_height,
                        id: "#newsletterContent",
                        doneFunc: function () {
                            console.log("done with page");
                            buildNewsletter();                                

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        setTimeout(buildNewsletter, 1000);                                      
    });

    function printForm() {
        window.print();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
doneFunc: function () {
                            console.log("done with page");
                            printForm();
```

Is this what you intended?

From what I understand, this runs when the function is finished.  Therefore, have the printForm() function run during the doneFunc() function.

Comment: print function is happen 2 times. first time it's print before columnize function is done and when i cancel print columnize is work done and then print is call again . how to call function print when columnize function is done.